# "all [object]'s [properties]" vs "[object]'s all [properties]"

Tags: syntactic-analysis, phrase-requests

Which form is correct and why?

1. "all [object]'s [properties]" OR
2. "[object]'s all [properties]"

Here's an example:

1. In order to use **all the machine's available cores**.
2. In order to use **the machine's all available cores**.

Comment: The first.  The second would never be used in normal text/speech.

Comment: Ok, but why? The second one looks perfectly reasonable from a syntactical point of view, doesn't it? The sentence is about all the available cores of the machine, hence the machine's all available cores (?). Is there any formal rule prohibiting this construction?

Comment: Neither. "All the available cores of the machine". Or simply "all the available cores", period. What is "the machine" even doing there in the first place.

Comment: And I don't know that I would say "leverage", either. As a software developer, I don't leverage cores. That's what the guys in marketing are for.

Comment: One problem with #2 is that it tends to suggest the term "all-available", which would be a complete change in meaning.

Comment: @RegDwigнt - How else do you pry them out of the machine?

Comment: @RegDwigнt, "the machine" is necessary if you want to clarify that you are specifically talking about the cores belonging to a particular machine (as oppossed to all cores in the universe).

Comment: (If you want to get technical, "cores" is wrong.  I have some "cores" sitting on the table next to me, and you'd be ill-advised to apply leverage to any of them, as they are quite fragile.)

Comment: What is the context that your reader can possibly think you might mean all the cores in the universe? Give me a lever and a place to stand and I will rewrite the sentence in two words. Heck, don't even give me the context. The word *available* all by itself already clearly says that it's specifically *not* all the cores in the universe. You don't have a point.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I'm using the word leverage with the meaning of "exploit, take advantage of, use to gain". The expression "leverage all cores" has already been used indeed (if you google the sentence including the quotation marks), although I admit there are very few matches. Maybe I should have used another expression.

Comment: I think you're missing my point. Rather than googling for "leverage", google for "marketese".

Comment: At any rate, all I'm saying here is this is an X for Y question. You're focusing on the curtains and not the elephant. You're putting lipstick on a chinchilla.

Comment: I replaced "leverage" with "use", so we can focus on the main point of the question.

Comment: @RegDwigнt, maybe the whole universe is a too far-fetched example, but for instance think of a cluster of computers, if someone simply says "all available cores" that could be understood to mean all the available cores in the whole cluster, even though the speaker's intention might have been all the available cores belonging to the particular computer with ID = 222.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In English, some [quantifiers](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/determiners/determiners-position-and-order), such as *all, much, both* (with plural nouns), *some, enough,* or *none of*, must come first in a noun phrase. When *both* quantifies plural personal pronouns the partitive construction with *of* is obligatory. If the phrase is an object, *both* may follow the definite article, but not generally as subject:

> He bought it for (the) both of *us/you/them*.
>   <del>The b</del>Both of *us/you/them* are going to the concert.

A possessive, however, can only be followed by *few, many,* and numerals — and, of course, any number of attributive adjectives.

> her few noteworthy accomplishments
>   their many friends
>   his one good overcoat

There are some errors native speakers simply don’t make. Word order mistakes with quantifiers are, fortunately, among them.

> *my all books
>   *All (of) my books were damaged in the flood.*
>
> *the much green grass
>   *Much of the once green grass has now withered.*
>
> *the village’s both decent restaurants
>   *Both (of) the village’s decent restaurants were closed.*

Comment: Would you mind adding the corrected version of your examples to your answer? Your third example looks very similar to the example of my question and I'm truly interested in knowing its corrected version.